# data comparison in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, diff, hdfs, cluster-computing

Can someone suggest the best and optimal solution for data comparison on 2 different clusters in hadoop? If on one cluster the incoming file is split in 10 blocks and stored in HDFS by MapReduce, and on the other cluster it is stored in 5 blocks and at the end of the day I want a difference in data in these 2 clusters.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By using the Hadoop FSCK command we can able to retrieve files info.

```
hadoop fsck / -files -blocks -locations
```

Rest of the arguments and commands are detailed here
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html#fsck .

Comment: Thanks Karthik for the quick reply. I am aware of this command. What I actually want is to compare data between 2 HDFS files and report an error on a per line basis. I am trying a checksum method, but not able to actually figure out how to do it efficiently. The 2 distributed files can be of TB size.

Comment: you can distcp the files want to compare from the HDFS and compare the files content with HIve or Pig . !!